# Retrieve matching rows based on partial strings between two data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, match

I'm looking for a way to retrieve rows from one dataframe based on criteria from another dataframe. Here's an illustrative example of what I'm trying to do:-

```
prefix<-c("0141", "0142", "0143", "0144", "0156", "0157", "0158", "0161")
IDnumbers<-c("01416783902", "014138926949", "01444783002", "07862738468", "01618769203", "015728936482", "07728394562","07264783959","02873819364")
IDnames<-c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii")

df1<-cbind(IDnames, IDnumbers)
df2<-cbind(prefix)
```

Essentially, I am trying to retrieve rows from my df by matching the 4-digit prefixes with the first 4 digits in the "IDnumbers" variable. I should end up with:-

```
aaa    01416783902
bbb    014138926949
ccc    01444783002
eee    01618769203
fff    015728936482
```

The code that I have tried, which failed to work properly is this:-

```
results<-sapply(df2$prefix, grep, df1$IDnumbers)
```

That didn't return the desired output. I imagine that there is solutions in the dplyr and data.table package but I haven't found any. Any suggestions would be most welcome! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to `paste` the `prefix` from `df2` in one string and `subset` the rows from `df1` which match that pattern.

```
subset(df1, grepl(paste0("^",df2$prefix, collapse = "|"), IDnumbers))

#  IDnames    IDnumbers
#1     aaa  01416783902
#2     bbb 014138926949
#3     ccc  01444783002
#5     eee  01618769203
#6     fff 015728936482
```

For reference, the pattern which is generated from the `paste0` statement is

```
paste0("^",df2$prefix, collapse = "|")
#[1] "^0141|^0142|^0143|^0144|^0156|^0157|^0158|^0161"
```

So it filters rows where `IDnumbers` start with any of these numbers.

**data**

Changed the format of your data so that they are dataframes instead of matrix.

```
prefix<-c("0141", "0142", "0143", "0144", "0156", "0157", "0158", "0161")
IDnumbers<-c("01416783902", "014138926949", "01444783002", "07862738468", 
      "01618769203", "015728936482", "07728394562","07264783959","02873819364")
IDnames<-c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii")

df1<-data.frame(IDnames, IDnumbers, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2<-data.frame(prefix, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just use `%in%` with exact match to get a logical vector after getting the `substr`ing of the 'IDnumbers'

```
subset(df1, substr(IDnumbers, 1, 4) %in% df2$prefix)
#   IDnames    IDnumbers
#1     aaa  01416783902
#2     bbb 014138926949
#3     ccc  01444783002
#5     eee  01618769203
#6     fff 015728936482
```

---

From `stringr` version 1.4.0 onwards, we can also use `str_starts/str_ends`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
    filter(str_starts(IDnumbers, paste(df2$prefix, collapse="|")))
# IDnames    IDnumbers
#1     aaa  01416783902
#2     bbb 014138926949
#3     ccc  01444783002
#4     eee  01618769203
#5     fff 015728936482
```

Comment: This solution worked really well, particularly the `stringr` solution. Thank you so much!! :)